# SQL Server and Async class error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: sql-server, android-asynctask

I'm developing an app with Android Studio, java. I perform some operations that require an Async class. After I started using such classes, other activities are no longer able to connect to Sql Server, returning the error message: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.

The Activity that is showing this error does not make any calls or uses Async routines. But after I implemented some Async class in my project, I can no longer minimally open a database in SQL Server.

Does anyone know what the problem is or can explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Async classes work perfectly fine without any issues.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. Android doesn't allow you to block the main (UI) thread with network access. This includes SQL Server queries because they require network access. You might want to research other options for wrapping up network access including `IntentService`s and `JobIntentService`s, or other threading patterns such as `Executor`s and `Handler`s.

Answer (score 0):

Request Data either local or network , It suppose to be request from Background Thread.

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // request 
                
                runOnUiThread(() -> { // main thread
                    // update ui
                });
            }
        };
        runnable.run();
```